# i am using codeigniter with bootstrap i got error?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

in code_igniter I use bootstrap CSS files
but when I link the css file in

home.php

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

In `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

i got this error

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/url_helper.php
```

Comment: try once by commenting that autoload and add $this->load->helper('url'); in controller

Answer (score 1):

First off check if you have loaded url helper any where else if so remove it and just have it autoload

With loading css you need to inclde `rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');?>">
```

This is what I have autoload for helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('array', 'form', 'date', 'html', 'text', 'url');
```

Check that the file exists in `system/helpers/url_helper`.

If you are creating your own url helper you may need to rename it and

```
application/helpers/custom_helper.php
```

Note: Codeigniter 3 case sensitive make sure your controller class names and file names only have the first letter uppercase `Welcome_something.php` and class `Welcome_something extends CI_Controller {}`